# Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}$ under some conditions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}$, with $f: (k_1,k_2)\to\Bbb R$ differentiable at $a\in (k_1,k_2)$, $\lim b_n=\lim a_n=a$, and $a_n<a<b_n$.

My attempt: Im trying to write the above equality as a particular case of this other equality that hold by any interior point $a$

$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}$$

Because $a_n<a<b_n$ then I can write

$$f'(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(h_n+a)-f(a-j_n)}{h_n+j_n}$$

Where $h_n=b_n-a>0$ and $j_n=a-a_n>0$, where these two new sequences tends monotonically to zero.

Now my problem: my thought is that $h_n$ and $j_n$ are particular sequences then I can build a sequence $k_n$ such that $j_n$ and $h_n$ are subsequences so I can write:

$$\{h_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\{k_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\text{ and }\{j_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\{k_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$$

(I can build this $k_n$ by example doing $k_{2n}=h_n$ and $k_{2n-1}=j_n$) and then I have the desired expression

$$f'(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(k_n+a)-f(a-k_n)}{2k_n}$$

My question:

1. Is this proof right? In particular Im unsure of the implicit statement "if the limit exist for $k_n$ then it must exist too for the particular case with $h_n$ and $j_n$". The use of two sequences, $h_n$ and $j_n$ in the limit make me unsure about the validity of this manipulation and assumption.
2. There is a simpler/different way to prove the same?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'(a)$ exists we have $$f(a_{n}) = f(a) + (a_{n} - a)f'(a) + (a_{n} - a)\eta_{n}$$ where $\eta_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Similarly $$f(b_{n}) = f(a) + (b_{n} - a)f'(a) + (b_{n} - a)\mu_{n}$$ where $\mu_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then we have $$f(b_{n}) - f(a_{n}) = (b_{n} - a_{n})f'(a) + (b_{n} - a)\mu_{n} - (a_{n} - a)\eta_{n}$$ and hence $$\left|\frac{f(b_{n}) - f(a_{n})}{b_{n} - a_{n}} - f'(a)\right| \leq \frac{|b_{n} - a|}{|b_{n} - a_{n}|}\cdot|\mu_{n}| + \frac{|a_{n} - a|}{|b_{n} - a_{n}|}\cdot|\eta_{n}|$$ and since $a_{n} < a < b_{n}$ it follows that the RHS of the above equation is less than $|\mu_{n}| + |\eta_{n}|$ and hence both LHS and RHS tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

Your proof has a problem because you seem to assume that $b_{n} - a = a - a_{n}$. This is not necessary.

---

It is possible to remove the constraint $a_{n} < a < b_{n}$ provided we assume that $b_{n} \neq a_{n}$ and $f'$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Im not assuming that $b_n-a=a-a_n$. I assume that each difference lead to different sequences $h_n$ and $j_n$.

Comment: @Masacroso: Then how do you get $b_{n} - a_{n} = 2k_{n}$ According to your definitions you should have $b_{n} - a_{n} = j_{n} + h_{n} = k_{2n} + k_{2n - 1}$.

Comment: $b_n-a_n\neq 2k_n$,I build a new sequence such that $b_n-a_n$ is a subsequence of $2k_n$. As you read my text?

Comment: @Masacroso: You are still not getting the point. What you are trying to do is not possible. Such a subsequencing is not possible. You think it is possible but it is not. The points $a + k_{n}$ and $a - k_{n}$ are equidistant from $a$ but $b_{n}, a_{n}$ are not equidistant from $a$.

Comment: @Masacroso: You are trying to base your proof on the result that $(f(a + h) - f(a - h))/2h \to f'(a)$. Instead you should base your answer of the proof of this result. The proof of the result $(f(a + h) - f(a - h))/2h \to f'(a)$ is done in exactly the same manner as I have done in my answer.

Comment: I think I understand where was my fault, yes you are right. I was trying to build a sequence to make the other subsequences... but this is valid for the sequence in the domain i.e. if we have some subsequence of $n\to\infty$ then the limit is the same. I was trying to do this inside of the limit, what is absurd. Your proof is very clear, thank you very much.